# Automatically execute script for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a script which calculates the metrics for yesterday automatically and inserts the data into the table, but I want to fill the table with all missing dates.Is it even possible to do automatically or I should manually start the script for each day?

Here is the simplified version of the script:

```
select  sum(amount),id,yesterday
where date < yesterday
group by id
```

But for example the day before yesterday is also missing in the table, so I want the above script to execute, and also the script:

```
select  sum(amount),id,day_before_yesterday
where date < day_before_yesterday
group by id
```

Comment: You can use `crontab` if on UNIX, or some similar tool on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

use the last date you have in the target table :

```
select  sum(amount),id, max(date)
from table
where date < (select max(date) - interval 1 day from target)
group by id
```

Comment: but still I will need to execute it manually, right? I mean that I won't need to change anything, just click on execute for every day

Comment: No. Put the above query in a script then run that script via `crontab` (or a Windows job scheduler). Or install the extension pg_cron;

Comment: @user5764 no need to change anything , just execute

Comment: @Belayer You mean to put it on schedule to execute e.g. every other hour, its that ideally later after filling all the missing dates this script should be executed only once a day  because dwh updates the tables only once a day

Comment: Schedule yes. Every hour? Your title and description indicate daily, but there is nothing preventing hourly. As @eshirvana points out there is no need to  change anything, their query adjusts for day.

Comment: @Belayer I got it that there is no need to change it, but what I can't understand is that to load the history(e.g. 14 days) you need to execute this script manually, because if you run it daily, you won't fill the table with historical data or am I overlooking smth?

Comment: @user5764 to explain the query : It looks at the destination table , and see what's the last date you have in that table and then grab all the missing dates rows from source table from there whenever you run the query